# positiveintegerfield's choice appears on frontende, but its key is visible. value does not appear

Tags: django

I'm developing a backend with the django rest api. I have the same problem with my advertise model except for my user model. My choice linked to positiveintegerfielder is not displayed in restframework for post method.I'm doing an action like in serializer.py, whose photo I shared to display. When I do this, it is not displayed in restframework and I cannot use the post method.

Thank you very much in advance

### serializer.py##

```
from user.models import User
from rest_auth.serializers import *

class ChoicesSerializerField(serializers.SerializerMethodField):
  def __init__(self, choices, **kwargs):
      self._choices = choices
      super(ChoicesSerializerField, self).__init__(**kwargs)

  def to_representation(self, value):
      # sample: 'get_XXXX_display'
      method_name = 'get_{field_name}_display'.format(field_name=self.field_name)
      # retrieve instance method
      method = getattr(value, method_name)
      # finally use instance method to return result of get_XXXX_display()
      return method()

  def to_internal_value(self, data):
      return getattr(self._choices, data)


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  gender = ChoicesSerializerField(choices=User.gender)
  class Meta:
      model = User
      fields = ('gender',)
```

### view.py##

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet

from user.serializer import UserSerializer
from .models import *
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework.generics import CreateAPIView, ListAPIView, GenericAPIView, get_object_or_404


class CreateUserView(ModelViewSet):
  queryset = User.objects.all()
  serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

### User model##

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
from django.db import models
from user.choices.choice import MartialStatusChoices, 
EducationalStatusChoices, ProfessionChoices, GenderChoices




class Interest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True  )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name






class User(AbstractUser):
    birthday = models.DateField(null=True)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$')
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], 
max_length=17, blank=True)
    gender = 
models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True,choices=GenderChoices.CHOICES)
martial_status =  models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, 
choices=MartialStatusChoices.CHOICES)
    educational_status = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, 
choices=EducationalStatusChoices.CHOICES)
    profession = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, 
choices=ProfessionChoices.CHOICES)
    interests = models.ManyToManyField(to=Interest,null=True, 
blank=True)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name= "User"
```

Comment: Only add a tag when your question requires a specialist in that technology to be answered. In your case a `vue` expert would be useless without knowledge on `django`.

Comment: I am very new in creating questions, thank you very much for your contributions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try `serializers.ChoiceField`.

```
from user.choices.choice import GenderChoices

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  gender = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=GenderChoices.CHOICES)
  
  class Meta:
      model = User
      fields = ('gender',)
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

class UserView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,) # remove this if you're using authentication

    def get(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(instance=request.user)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(instance=request.user, data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response()
```

Comment: very thank you. I've tried this situation before. Now I tried again and returned an error like this.               
  File "C:\Users\sabca\PycharmProjects\yerliyabanci\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py", line 143, in to_choices_dict
    for choice in choices:
TypeError: 'DeferredAttribute' object is not iterable

Comment: I asked you for models to see how you're handling choices, try to import choices directly to serializer field. I've changed my answer.

Comment: I've tried this before. This time it appears in api, but when the option is selected, it was not registered. It does not register with the put method, but currently it registers with the patch method.
I've realized now. I will try well and be back, thank you very much.

Comment: @sananesanane Ok, I will give you an example of how I like to write a view.

Comment: When this happens, numbers appear on the front end. key values ​​are not visible :'( so I'm actually viewing the choicefield, but it doesn't correspond to the frontend. for example, the value of number 1 is male. male does not write 1 writes